# Dependency issue during deleting mysql in Debian stretch

Tags: debian, mysql, dependencies

I need to install mysql-server-5.7, but the highest version in debian repo is 5.6. I've tried to find the way to install 5.7. Can't remember all tried, but I didn't manage to to that. Instead of it I have now new issue. When I try to delete mysql-5.6, I get this:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.6.30-1) but 5.6.34-1debian8 is to be installed
 libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.6.34-1debian8)
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 232-6)
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.6
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 232-3) but 232-6 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And even purge doesn't work..

One more detail - I can't apply system updates. When I try to run update with Gnome Package Updater, I get "Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config_editor.1.gz', which is also in package mysql-client-5.6 5.6.30-1"

`sudo apt-get -f install` doesn't work

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc firebird2.5-server-common firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 imagemagick-common libappindicator3-1 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec57:i386 libavresample3:i386 libavutil55:i386 libboost-atomic1.61.0 libboost-chrono1.61.0 libboost-thread1.61.0 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcrystalhd3:i386 libcups2:i386 libcurl3 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libfbclient2
  libfbembed2.5 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreetype6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libice6:i386 libidn11:i386 libindicator3-7
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg62-turbo:i386 libjson-c3:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 liblz4-1:i386 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 libmng1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libnettle6:i386 libnuma1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosinfo-db libp11-kit0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386
  libshine3:i386 libsm6:i386 libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libswresample2:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtommath1 libtwolame0:i386 libva-drm1:i386 libva-x11-1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau-va-gl1:i386
  libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvncclient1 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx4:i386 libvte-common libvte9 libwavpack1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux2:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx264-148:i386 libx265-95:i386 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shape0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxi6:i386 libxnvctrl0 libxrender1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libzvbi0:i386 linux-image-4.6.0-1-amd64 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 node-sigmund psensor-common python-gobject qt-at-spi:i386 va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vlc-nox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient-dev libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 mysql-common:i386 systemd udev
Suggested packages:
  systemd-ui systemd-container
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-common:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient-dev libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 systemd udev
5 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5,442 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,047 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 libmysqlclient-dev amd64 5.6.34-1debian8 [1,124 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.org.ua/debian stretch/main amd64 udev amd64 232-6 [1,100 kB]
Get:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie/mysql-5.6 i386 mysql-common i386 5.6.34-1debian8 [203 kB]
Get:4 http://debian.org.ua/debian stretch/main amd64 systemd amd64 232-6 [2,452 kB]
Get:5 http://debian.org.ua/debian stretch/main i386 libsystemd0 i386 232-6 [290 kB]
Get:6 http://debian.org.ua/debian stretch/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 232-6 [273 kB]
Fetched 5,442 kB in 2s (2,341 kB/s)  
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 170515 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.34-1debian8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient-dev (5.6.34-1debian8) over (5.6.30-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-mNfUdL/0-libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.34-1debian8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config_editor.1.gz', which is also in package mysql-client-5.6 5.6.30-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mysql-common_5.6.34-1debian8_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common:i386 (5.6.34-1debian8) over (5.8+1.0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-mNfUdL/1-mysql-common_5.6.34-1debian8_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys', which is also in package mysql-server-core-5.6 5.6.30-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-mNfUdL/0-libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.34-1debian8_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-mNfUdL/1-mysql-common_5.6.34-1debian8_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's going on here and how can it be fixed? :)

Comment: It's better and more easy way to use _sid_ repository when you already using _testing_ (mysql-server-5.7=5.7.16-1). Fix with `apt-get -f install` as the error message said.

Comment: @IporSircer `apt-get -f install` doesn't work. Added output to description. I believe I I screwed up with dependencies somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-core-5.6.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-client-5.6.list
apt-get -f install
```

Next time avoid from manually installing not debian released packages on Debian.